# Max number of records in mapping XML-to-XML with Mule Studio

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I'm trying to do a simple mapping from a XML to another XML using mule studio, but when I run the flow I get this error:

Invalid mapping (Port binding to a root element may produce invalid XML file. Set 'Records per file' or 'Max number of records' component attributes to '1'.)

Any suggestions how to setup the "Max number of records"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you are effectively creating a target XML that has more than one root element, this would be an invalid XML. Ideally your mapping should not create such target.

However, if it's difficult to fix you should workaroud the problem edition the CloverETL used b datamapper.In that file, find your root Node entry in the mapping file and add recordsPerFile="1" attribute.

Take into consideration that the first solution is very recommended, as this manual change of the second one will be loss on file regeneration.